# smoothing capacitor for power supply

Tags: capacitor

First off, this is my first post and I know enough about electronics to get myself in trouble.
I want to build an electric drive for my 25 foot sailboat, but instead of running it on batteries, I want to run it off a 2500watt ac generator To save weight and provide power for coffee maker and such.
I have so far:
130vdc motorrated at 3hp continous
1000volt,50 Amp bridge rectifier
Switch to reverse polarity

My question is, how big of a capacitor do I need to smooth the dirty dc power for the rectifier?

Comment: None at all.  The motor can deal with the ripple.

Comment: Have you examined what the stall current of the motor is i.e. if you get a load of sea weed tangled up in the blades.

Comment: Is 3 HP enough to make this project worthwhile?

Answer (score 1):

No filter cap at all will be necessary.  But for reversing, you are going to want to put a time delay between forward and reverse, preferably use something like a three pole switch, and give the motor some time to spin down before switching its direction.
And you might want to forget just feeding the bridge rectifier directly, and look at an SCR drive controller or even heavy duty SCR light dimmer to feed it.  That will give you variable speed.  If using a drive controller, you won't need the rectifier.  If using just a heavy duty light dimmer, you will.

Answer (score 0):

1. if the generator is 3 phase you may not require a filter capacitor else motor inductance should be enough to avoid discontinuity in the motor current. people do use eries inductance to avoid said issue.
   vtingole